# Except is not working with embedded sql query

Tags: sql, select, except

I'm having this problem, and it really grinds my gears, because I really cannot find a solution. I'm working in SQL Server Management Studio.
Here, I select distinct data and the average of another column's values for each distinct data, like this:

```
SELECT age, standing
FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT standing, avg(age) as age
FROM student
group by standing) as s
```

Now, this works fine. The problem occurs, when I try to do this:

```
SELECT age, standing
FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT standing, avg(age) as age
FROM student
group by standing) as s

EXCEPT 

SELECT age, standing
FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT standing, avg(age) as age
FROM student
WHERE standing = 'JR'
group by standing) as k
```

The select above EXCEPT and below EXCEPT works fine, but together they just don't. The program tells me an error about the except:
There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 6,Token line offset = 1,Token in error = EXCEPT ]

I also tried UNION, INTERSECT and MINUS. Only union seemed to work, and for now I really don't know what's going on here.

I'm looking forward for the solution, and also really interested what am I doing wrong.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 10.50.1600.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to exclude records with 'JR' standing?
Why not try this:

```
SELECT age, standing
FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT standing, avg(age) as age
FROM student
where standing <> 'JR'
group by standing) as s
```

Comment: Thank you very much! :) It works exactly as I wanted.
But anyway, don't you know what causes this problem with EXCEPT? I'm just curious about this.

Answer (score 0):

Can you run this query 'select @@version' and tell the information you get.
I tried a query similar to your's on my "sql sever 2008" and it is working fine.
Also when you use union,intersect and except you don't need to use distinct, it won't cause any problem but is not needed as they return distinct rows.

Comment: It doesn't work, it throws an error that the global variable name is not valid.
Anyway I use version 10.50.1600.1.